# Some Misunderstanding in Basics of the Installation of Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I am trying Linux Mint 18 as my first Linux. When installing, I had to shrink my hard disk partitions, but every single tutorial I find talks about unallocated space while in my case it's shown as free space (every single partition has it own space they are not all mixed up). Now my questions.

- Is it correct to install that way ? (the space is free not unallocated)
- Should I create a new partition for the swap or will it just create it itself? (and since I have 4GB RAM, what is the needed size for this partition?)
- in case I don't like the OS, can I reconfigure the boot using EasyBCD on Windows 8.1 ?
- in the following picture there is a 32GB Partition. What is that?

ps : I know this question may have been asked before but I can't find answer for my questions some of the questions may be a duplicates but I need answer for the rest.n,

[image: Disk Management]

Comment: You speak about Linux Mint and then show a screenshot of a Windows utility. There is no law requiring Windows to use the same teminology as Linux. About the 32 GiB partition -- it's on _your_ disk; _you_ made it or allowed it to exist. If _you_ don't know what it's for then how could we? It may be a Windows recovery partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just **format** the partition. Thats why it seems to free space.For installing OS you need unallocated space. If you delete the free space partition then its seems as a unallocated space. Then you are able to  install OS

```
    Step 1 : delete the free space partition
```

If you install OS on unallocated space two OS still exist.

**swap** is actually a filesystem. After formating a partition with swap filesystem those partition act as a virtual RAM. its optional. If you think that I have enough RAM no need to create.It will not create automatically. But if you not create swap partition system will give you a warring. Don't stop your installation process.

**32GB Partition** is partition with filesystem(NTFS or FAT) but not mounted. Without mounted user not access the space.If you access the space you may assign a mount point(**Like local(C)**) by right click on that partition.